# Is it possible to use Django's admin portal when using a graph database?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, graph-databases

Is there any way I can use the django's admin portal? At least reuse the UI rendering?

I'll be using Django + graph database for my application. So my models will not be extending django.db.models.Model. Instead it'll be extending a Node class provided by graph DB's library. The application also uses JWT based authentication (with a custom JWT middleware).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin is quite tightly coupled to the ORM. You could try to:

- write a `ModelAdmin` subclass that can handle your `Node` classes, but I doubt you would be able to reuse a lot of code
- write a wrapper around your `Node` classes that provides an interface identical to `django.db.models.Model`

If you are not using Django's authentication mechanism, this complicates things to a point where I think it is not worth the hassle and you are probably better of rolling your own solution based on plain forms.